# grep or gsub for everything except a specific string in R

Tags: r, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to match everything except a specific string in `R`, and I've seen a bunch of posts on this suggesting a `negative lookaround,` but I haven't gotten that to work.

I have a dataset looking at crime incidents in SF, and I want to sort cases that have a resolution or do not. In the resolution field, cases have things listed like arrest booked, arrest cited, juvenile booked, etc., or none. I want to relabel all the specific resolutions like the different arrests to "RESOLVED" and keep the instances with "NONE" as such. So, I thought I could gsub or grep for not "NONE".

Based on what I've read on finding all strings except one specific string, I would have thought this would work:

```
resolution_vector = grep("^(?!NONE$).*", trainData$Resolution, fixed=TRUE)
```

Where I make a vector that searches through my training dataset, specifically the resolution column, and finds the terms that aren't "NONE". But, I just get an empty vector.

Does anyone have suggestions, or know why this might not be working in R? Or, even if there was a way to just use gsub, how do I say "not NONE" for my regex in R?

`trainData$Resolution = gsub("!NONE", RESOLVED, trainData$Resolution) <<` what's the way to negate the string here?

Comment: Maybe `trainData$Resolution[!grepl("NONE", trainData$Resolution, fixed=T)] <- "RESOLVED"`. And make sure the column isn't `factor` class.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation, it seems as though you don't need regular expressions (i.e. `gsub()`) at all.  You can use `!=` since you are looking for all non-matches of an exact string.  Perhaps you want

```
within(trainData, {
    ## next line only necessary if you have a factor column
    Resolution <- as.character(Resolution)
    Resolution[Resolution != "NONE"] <- "RESOLVED"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resolution_vector = grep("^(?!NONE$).*", trainData$Resolution, fixed=TRUE,perl=TRUE)
```

You need to use option `perl=TRUE`.